# Why servlet-api.jar turns its status from test to compile?

Tags: java, maven-2, maven, openejb

This is what I have in `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey.jersey-test-framework</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-grizzly</artifactId>
  <version>1.4</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

This is what I see after `mvn --debug war:war`:

```
[...]
[DEBUG]    com.sun.jersey.jersey-test-framework:jersey-test-framework-grizzly:jar:1.4:test
[DEBUG]       com.sun.jersey.jersey-test-framework:jersey-test-framework-core:jar:1.4:test
[DEBUG]          org.glassfish:javax.servlet:jar:3.0-b66:test
[DEBUG]       com.sun.grizzly:grizzly-servlet-webserver:jar:1.9.18-i:test
[DEBUG]          com.sun.grizzly:grizzly-http:jar:1.9.18-i:test
[DEBUG]             com.sun.grizzly:grizzly-framework:jar:1.9.18-i:test
[DEBUG]             com.sun.grizzly:grizzly-rcm:jar:1.9.18-i:test
[DEBUG]             com.sun.grizzly:grizzly-portunif:jar:1.9.18-i:test
[DEBUG]          com.sun.grizzly:grizzly-http-servlet:jar:1.9.18-i:test
[DEBUG]             com.sun.grizzly:grizzly-utils:jar:1.9.18-i:test
[DEBUG]          javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:compile
[...]
```

Pay attention to the last line. Why it's not `"test"`, but `"compile"`?

ps. Indeed it's very weird. This is my complete `pom.xml` (sorry, it's not short):

```
[...]
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.7</version> <!-- 10 Sep 2010 -->
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>xom</groupId>
    <artifactId>xom</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version> <!-- 13 Oct 2010 -->
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.5</version> <!-- 9 Oct 2010 -->
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version> <!-- 9 Oct 2010 -->
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
    <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version> <!-- 12 Oct 2010 -->
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version> <!-- 2 Nov 2010 -->
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <!-- version see below in dependencyManagement section -->
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <!-- version see below in dependencyManagement section -->
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey.jersey-test-framework</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-grizzly</artifactId>
    <!-- version see below in dependencyManagement section -->
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <!-- version see below in dependencyManagement section -->
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
    <artifactId>openejb-ejbd</artifactId>
    <!-- version see below in dependencyManagement section -->
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
    <!-- version see below in dependencyManagement section -->
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
    <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    <!-- version see below in dependencyManagement section -->
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version> <!-- 9 Oct 2010 -->
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
      <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
      <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
      <version>${jersey.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey.jersey-test-framework</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-grizzly</artifactId>
      <version>${jersey.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
      <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
      <artifactId>openejb-ejbd</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.3</version> <!-- 26 October 2010 -->
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.2</version> <!-- 29 oct 2010 -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
      <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.0.10</version> <!-- 12 October 2010 -->
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
[...]
```

This is how `maven-war-plugin` is configured:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.0</version>
  <configuration>
    <archive>
      <manifestEntries>
        <SCM-Revision>${buildNumber}</SCM-Revision>
      </manifestEntries>
    </archive>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Do you have javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5 as part of your <dependencyManagement>?

Comment: @Buhb See the updated version of my question

Comment: Did you configure the maven-war-plugin with servlet-api dependency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I've done to solve the problem:

```
[...]
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
[...]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is very very weird, I don't get the same output when running `mvn` with `--debug`:

```
$ mvn --debug compile
...
[DEBUG]    com.sun.jersey.jersey-test-framework:jersey-test-framework-grizzly:jar:1.4:test
[DEBUG]       com.sun.jersey.jersey-test-framework:jersey-test-framework-core:jar:1.4:test
[DEBUG]          com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:jar:1.4:test
[DEBUG]             com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.4:test
[DEBUG]             asm:asm:jar:3.1:test
[DEBUG]          com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:jar:1.4:test
[DEBUG]          org.glassfish:javax.servlet:jar:3.0-b66:test
[DEBUG]       com.sun.grizzly:grizzly-servlet-webserver:jar:1.9.18-i:test
[DEBUG]          com.sun.grizzly:grizzly-http:jar:1.9.18-i:test
[DEBUG]             com.sun.grizzly:grizzly-framework:jar:1.9.18-i:test
[DEBUG]             com.sun.grizzly:grizzly-rcm:jar:1.9.18-i:test
[DEBUG]             com.sun.grizzly:grizzly-portunif:jar:1.9.18-i:test
[DEBUG]          com.sun.grizzly:grizzly-http-servlet:jar:1.9.18-i:test
[DEBUG]             com.sun.grizzly:grizzly-utils:jar:1.9.18-i:test
[DEBUG]          javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:test
...
```

Which is coherent with the `dependency:tree`:

```
$ mvn dependency:tree 
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
...
[INFO] \- com.sun.jersey.jersey-test-framework:jersey-test-framework-grizzly:jar:1.4:test
[INFO]    +- com.sun.jersey.jersey-test-framework:jersey-test-framework-core:jar:1.4:test
[INFO]    |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:jar:1.4:test
[INFO]    |  |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.4:test
[INFO]    |  |  \- asm:asm:jar:3.1:test
[INFO]    |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:jar:1.4:test
[INFO]    |  \- org.glassfish:javax.servlet:jar:3.0-b66:test
[INFO]    \- com.sun.grizzly:grizzly-servlet-webserver:jar:1.9.18-i:test
[INFO]       +- com.sun.grizzly:grizzly-http:jar:1.9.18-i:test
[INFO]       |  +- com.sun.grizzly:grizzly-framework:jar:1.9.18-i:test
[INFO]       |  +- com.sun.grizzly:grizzly-rcm:jar:1.9.18-i:test
[INFO]       |  \- com.sun.grizzly:grizzly-portunif:jar:1.9.18-i:test
[INFO]       +- com.sun.grizzly:grizzly-http-servlet:jar:1.9.18-i:test
[INFO]       |  \- com.sun.grizzly:grizzly-utils:jar:1.9.18-i:test
[INFO]       \- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:test
...
```

The `servlet-api` artifact has a `test` scope as expected.

Do you have the `servlet-api` declared as dependency with a `compile` scope somewhere? That's the only way I could reproduce.

---

**Update:** I reproduced the output with `mvn --debug` after pasting all dependencies your provided. That said, I don't know how to interpret this output which is printed when the `maven-compiler-plugin` is executed. Also note that it differs from the `dependency:tree`:

```
$ mvn dependency:tree 
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
...
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:tree (default-cli) @ Q4098082 ---
[INFO] com.stackoverflow:Q4098082:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.7:test
[INFO] +- xom:xom:jar:1.2.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.03:compile
[INFO] |  +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.8.5:test
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-io:jar:1.3.2:test
[INFO] +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:1.6.2:compile
[INFO] +- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- asm:asm:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:jar:1.4:test
[INFO] +- com.sun.jersey.jersey-test-framework:jersey-test-framework-grizzly:jar:1.4:test
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.jersey.jersey-test-framework:jersey-test-framework-core:jar:1.4:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish:javax.servlet:jar:3.0-b66:test
[INFO] |  \- com.sun.grizzly:grizzly-servlet-webserver:jar:1.9.18-i:test
[INFO] |     +- com.sun.grizzly:grizzly-http:jar:1.9.18-i:test
[INFO] |     |  +- com.sun.grizzly:grizzly-framework:jar:1.9.18-i:test
[INFO] |     |  +- com.sun.grizzly:grizzly-rcm:jar:1.9.18-i:test
[INFO] |     |  \- com.sun.grizzly:grizzly-portunif:jar:1.9.18-i:test
[INFO] |     +- com.sun.grizzly:grizzly-http-servlet:jar:1.9.18-i:test
[INFO] |     |  \- com.sun.grizzly:grizzly-utils:jar:1.9.18-i:test
[INFO] |     \- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:test
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:3.5.6-Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:3.5.6-Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-annotations:jar:3.5.6-Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:3.2.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- cglib:cglib:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- javassist:javassist:jar:3.9.0.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.8:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.openejb:openejb-ejbd:jar:3.1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.openejb:javaee-api:jar:5.0-3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.openejb:openejb-core:jar:3.1.3:test
[INFO] |  |  +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.12:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.openejb:ejb31-api-experimental:jar:3.1.3:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.openejb:openejb-api:jar:3.1.3:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.openejb:openejb-javaagent:jar:3.1.3:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.openejb:openejb-jee:jar:3.1.3:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:wstx-asl:jar:3.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.1.9:test
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.activemq:activemq-ra:jar:5.3.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.activemq:activemq-core:jar:5.3.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging-api:jar:1.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jms_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.activemq:activeio-core:jar:3.1.2:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.activemq:kahadb:jar:5.3.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.activemq.protobuf:activemq-protobuf:jar:1.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-j2ee-management_1.0_spec:jar:1.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- commons-net:commons-net:jar:2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.openjpa:openjpa:jar:1.2.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- net.sourceforge.serp:serp:jar:1.13.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.components:geronimo-connector:jar:2.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.components:geronimo-transaction:jar:2.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.objectweb.howl:howl:jar:1.0.1-1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.javamail:geronimo-javamail_1.4_mail:jar:1.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.xbean:xbean-asm-shaded:jar:3.7:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.xbean:xbean-finder-shaded:jar:3.7:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.xbean:xbean-reflect:jar:3.7:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.xbean:xbean-naming:jar:3.7:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.openejb:commons-dbcp-all:jar:1.3-r699049:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.swizzle:swizzle-stream:jar:1.0.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.1:test
[INFO] |  |  \- quartz:quartz:jar:1.5.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.openejb:openejb-server:jar:3.1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.openejb:openejb-loader:jar:3.1.3:test
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.openejb:openejb-client:jar:3.1.3:test
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:jar:1.4.2:compile
[INFO] +- hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:1.8.0.10:test
[INFO] \- javax:javaee-api:jar:6.0:provided
...
```

The above is my reference to analyze the scope of dependencies and it looks correct. I don't know why the `maven-compiler-plugin` outputs a different result in debug mode, I don't know if this is expected, I never pay attention to the output.

Additional remark, the `javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5` is on the (huge) test classpath during the `compiler:testCompile` execution.

So while I don't have a full explanation, I can't spot any side effect.

Comment: I updated my question with a complete copy of what I have in `pom.xml`. Maybe it will help?

Comment: Do you need "full explanation" from me, or you meant some other source of information?

Comment: @Vincenzo: No, I mean that *I* can't explain the output obtained when running `mvn --debug`.

Comment: If you don't know ... I give up :)

Comment: This is exactly about my case: http://usna86-techbits.blogspot.com/2009/12/tomcat-openejb-and-jersey-oh-my.html